# How to call a macro from another workbook?

Tags: vba

I deal with order processing for a few retailers at my business and I manipulate the orders in excel worksheets. I import data from a query for each retailer and this process is the same across the 4 or 5 different accounts. But later steps differ, so each retailer has its own workbook.

What I am attempting to do is automate the process of importing the data from the query to each workbook through the use of formulas in the workbook as well as VBA. But I wanted to consolidate the macros into one workbook (basically a macro database other worksheets can call from) since I don't want to have to change the code in 5 separate workbooks every time I make an adjustment.

I have already attempted to put the code in the macro database and then just call the macro from each individual workbook and some of it has somewhat worked.

Here is one of the macros I originally had in each workbook and it works fine when in each workbook.

```
Private Sub OrderNumbers()

Dim myValue1 As Variant
Dim myValue2 As Variant
myValue1 = InputBox("What is your first order number?")
myValue2 = InputBox("What is your last order number?")
Range("A7").Value = myValue1
Range("A9").Value = myValue2

End Sub
```

Here is another macro.

```
Private Sub FillFormulas()

Dim myValue3 As Long
myValue3 = Range("A13").Value
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & myValue3)
Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & myValue3)
Range("D2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & myValue3)
Range("E2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & myValue3)
Range("F2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & myValue3)
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & myValue3)
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & myValue3)
Range("I2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & myValue3)
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & myValue3)

End Sub
```

I then moved the code to the database, and in each retailer workbook I put this code connected to buttons:

```
Private Sub Start_Click()
Excel.Run "Macros.xlsm!OrderNumbers()"
End Sub
```

For the OrderNumbers() macro, it calls it, but it calls it twice for some reason. However, the FillFormulas() macro doesn't work at all.

Comment: are there any error messages shown ?

Comment: As I Said in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57792039/11167163) I think that you need to try with Application.Run . Don't least to read the **Note** Even if you are using `Excel.Run`

Comment: @Dorian to address the issue you've indicated, the macro could also have the other workbook set as an object variable, right? This way, we ensure it's opened via the code itself.

Comment: Sure @BrenoTeodoro I am not behinf my computer yet i will update my answer so if he don’t know how to do he will know :)

Comment: @Aedvald Tseh No error messages appear when running this. It just doesn't run properly.

@Dorian I tried running with `Application.Run` instead of `Excel.Run` but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `Application.Run`

```
Application.Run "'Another Workbook.xlsm'!NameOfMacro"
```

The `'` marks are needed when the workbook name contains a space. If there is no space, the `'` marks are not required.  The code will still run correctly if they are included, so I recommend to use them for consistency.

**NOTE :** That the `workbook` which contains the macro **MUST** be open. If the `workbook` isn't open you will need to open it before runing the macro.

Hope this helps, Waiting for your feedbacks.

**BONUS** It's better to avoid `select` so I did it for you :

```
Private Sub FillFormulas()

Dim myValue3 As Long
myValue3 = Range("A13").Value
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & myValue3)
Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & myValue3)
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & myValue3)
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & myValue3)
Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & myValue3)
Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & myValue3)
Range("H2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & myValue3)
Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & myValue3)
Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & myValue3)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the process I used. That's what this is:

     `Excel.Run "Macros.xlsm!OrderNumbers()"`

I ran it both with and without the single quotes. And I also ran it with both workbooks open. No dice.

Comment: @Aaron do you have any error message so I can identify your real issue ?

Comment: No error messages pop up. When I call that first macro, it runs it two times, but it works. When I call the second macro, nothing happens.

Comment: @Aaron The best way to solve this issue is to use the debugger so you understand what is doing your macro. Do you know how it works ? 
**NB** I edited my answer to make your `FillFormulas` sub avoid `Select`

Comment: I changed the `FillFormulas()` macro to what you have above, but it still did not work. I ran through the debugger. When running through each line in the macro database, it worked fine. But when running through the `Application.Run "'Another Workbook.xlsm'!NameOfMacro"`, there is some kind of disconnect. Same results as before, runs the first macro double, second one doesn't run at all.

Comment: @Aaron can you put the entiere sub where you call macros from other workbooks ? I will try to debug it

Comment: In my original question, the `Private Sub OrderNumbers()` and `Private Sub Start_Click()` are the full codes I am using. `Private Sub OrderNumbers()` is in the database and `Private Sub Start_Click()` is in the individual worksheets.

Comment: @Aaron and what if you delete `()` : `Excel.Run "Macros.xlsm!OrderNumbers"`

Comment: @Aaron Glad I could help you